# Loop over tensor of vectors (size [batch_size, 1, 28])

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I have a network where a vector of size [1,28] is generated for every input in a batch (of size 128). Now I want to access the values in these vectors for the whole batch, so I want to return all 28 values for the 128 inputs in the batch. In other words, I want to loop over a tensor of size [128, 1, 28]. I could use multiple for-loops, but is there a nice pythonic way to achieve this?

Edit:
I'm asking because I want to eventually compute the gradients of each of the z_i in the vector z with respect to one of my network layer's output. I'm working with a variational autoencoder, where the encoder network outputs a mean and variance which is reparameterized to a latent vector z of size [1, 28]. Now given this vector z, I want to compute gradients for each element z_i wrt to the output of an earlier layer in the encoder. I hope this clarifies things!

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with these values and if there's a possible vectorized form for this calculation. Could you share with us what you are looking to do with those tensors?

Comment: Yes I'd like to calculate gradients wrt to these values, although I wasn't sure yet how to do that (wanted to figure the for look out first)

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: Can you provide the code sample with multiple `for` lopps that you mention ? We'll try to "pythonize" it from here